# Airflow Trigger Rule Task dependencies

Tags: airflow

In below shown DAG I want to execute task `d` no matter whether tasks `b` & `c` are success or failed, But for task `e` If tasks `b`, `c` & `d` are success then  only it should be triggered. [DAG Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/telkB.png)

Written below code but it is not working:

```
with DAG(dag_id='test_dag', default_args=args, schedule_interval=None) as dag:
   t_test = PythonOperator(task_id='test', python_callable=test)
   t_a = PythonOperator(task_id='a', python_callable=a)
   t_b = PythonOperator(task_id='b', python_callable=b)
   t_c = PythonOperator(task_id='c', python_callable=c)
   t_d = PythonOperator(task_id='d', python_callable=d, trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE)
   t_e = PythonOperator(task_id='e', python_callable=e, trigger_rule='all_success')
t_test >> t_a >> [t_b, t_c] >> t_d >> t_e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code the branch of your workflow tree in separate statements.

```py
# execute task d no matter whether tasks b & c succeeded or failed
t_test >> t_a >> [t_b, t_c] >> t_d

# execute task e if tasks b, c & d succeeded

t_e << [t_b, t_c, t_d]
```